# Shiny: how to choose a dataframe as input in a Rmd document Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm having trouble choosing a dataframe variable in Shiny as input.

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput("a", label = "N:",
              choices = c(1,2, 3, 4), selected = 1),
  selectInput("dataframe", label = "dataframe",
              choices = c(A,B), selected = A)
)
```

In renderPlot I have input$k working fine, as it is a simple numer.

However, for input$dataframe it is not working.
I am getting the error: `non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectInput` returns a character vector. You probably want to give the names of the datasets, and then evaluate them, rather than trying to pass the dataset itself.

From the help for `selectInput`:

> Server value: A vector of character strings, usually of length 1, with the value of the selected items. When multiple=TRUE and nothing is selected, this value will be NULL.

Full example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("data",
        "Select dataset",
        choices = c("iris", "mtcars")
    ),
    dataTableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
        get(input$data)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am working inside a Rmd document, so the syntax is a bit different from a Shiny app. Mu datasets are actually dataframes (my fault for the wrong terminology). How to choose between dataframes names A and B? Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference. You need to refer to them by variable name as a character string, like in the code I posted.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this before, using quotation marks, but I keep getting the same error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". When I use input$data, I have also tried to pass it as data.frame (as.data.frame(input$data)) but did not work.

Comment: Did you use `get(input$data)`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked now! I can't understand, as with the other input I did not have to use get. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. `get` is used to return the value of an object passed as a character string. For most Shiny inputs, you just need to work with the string, so you don't need to use it often.